# How to show data in the following format from database?

Tags: mysql, sql

#### Database Table Structure

[image]

#### Data need to show

[image]

**`Please note:`** The `city_from` and `city_to` not fixed. It comes from `city` table. But `single_or_group_id` is fixed `1 = Single` and `2 = Group`.

Comment: Show your attempt and producing the desired result set.

Answer (score 0):

> Should try this. Think it will work according to your condition

```
select a.Trans_rent as Single, b.Trans_rent as Group 
from table as a 
inner join table as b on a.city_from = b.city_from and a.city_to = b.city_to 
and b.single_or_group_id = 2 
where a.single_or_group_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see this. Hope it will help you.

```
<?php

$map_city = ['2'=>'Madina','3'=>'Makkah'];
$single_group = ['1'=>'Single','2'=>'Group'];

$data = [
    [
        'city_form' => 2,
        'city_to' => 3,
        'single_or_group_id' => 1,
        'rent' => 1000
    ],

    [
        'city_form' => 2,
        'city_to' => 3,
        'single_or_group_id' => 2,
        'rent' => 4000
    ],

];

?>

<table style="width:25%" border=1>

    <?php $is_first = true; ?>
    <?php foreach($data as $single){ ?>

    <?php if($is_first) { ?>
      <tr>
          <th colspan=2><?php echo $map_city[$single['city_form']] .'-'. $map_city[$single['city_to']];?></th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <?php foreach($data as $single){ ?>
             <td><?php echo $single_group[$single['single_or_group_id']];?></td>
         <?php } ?>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <?php foreach($data as $single){ ?>
             <td><?php echo 'S.R '.$single['rent'];?></td>
         <?php } ?>
      </tr>

        <?php $is_first = false; } ?>

    <?php } ?>

</table>
```